# How to Properly Sort and Combine Feeds in MongoDB's Aggregation Pipeline?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation-framework

I am querying MongoDB to retrieve feeds based on specific criteria. The initial requirement is to fetch all the feeds belonging to the logged-in user and the users they are following. These results should be sorted based on the creation date and score. Subsequently, I need to retrieve the remaining feeds from the database, sort them as well, and apply a limit of 20 on the combined results.

The problem I am facing is that when using the aggregation pipeline, the result from the previous stage is always used as input for the subsequent stage. However, I am seeking a solution to achieve a different behavior at the database layer using the aggregation framework, rather than handling it in Java. Could someone please provide guidance on the necessary changes required to meet this requirement?

To illustrate, let's consider an example where there are a total of four feeds in the database:

Feed 1 belongs to the logged-in user.
Feeds 2 and 4 belong to other users.
Feed 3 belongs to a user that the logged-in user is following.
In this scenario, the desired output would be: 1, 3, 2, 4.

```
    @Override
    public List<StoryDoc> getInfiniteFeedsNew(String userId, Integer skip, Integer limit){

        //get all the users which logged-in user is following
        List<String> followings = userDbAdapter.getLoggedInUserFollowings(userId);

        List<AggregationOperation> pipeline = new ArrayList<>();

        // Match stage to include the logged-in user and their followings
        MatchOperation matchIncludeUserAndFollowings = Aggregation.match(new Criteria().orOperator(
                Criteria.where(DocumentFields.OWNER_ID).in(followings),
                Criteria.where(DocumentFields.OWNER_ID).is(userId)
        ));
        pipeline.add(matchIncludeUserAndFollowings);


        pipeline.add(Aggregation.sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, DocumentFields.SCORE, DocumentFields.CREATED_ON));
        

        // Match stage to include all other feeds
        MatchOperation matchIncludeAllFeeds = Aggregation.match(new Criteria().andOperator(
                Criteria.where(DocumentFields.OWNER_ID).ne(userId),
                Criteria.where(DocumentFields.OWNER_ID).nin(followings)
        ));
        pipeline.add(matchIncludeAllFeeds);

        pipeline.add(Aggregation.sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, DocumentFields.SCORE, DocumentFields.CREATED_ON));

        // Skip stage to skip the requested number of stories
        pipeline.add(Aggregation.skip(skip));


        // Limit stage to limit the number of stories returned
        pipeline.add(Aggregation.limit(limit));
        
        

        Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(pipeline);
        AggregationResults<StoryDoc> aggregationResults = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, CollectionNames.STORY, StoryDoc.class);
        return new ArrayList();
}
```

I have tried the above code but it is not working as per the requirement above.

Comment: At a glance I think what you want is `$unionWith`. May need to add some sort key to documents in each group for use at the end of the pipeline but that really depends on your specific business logic